# flatMap reuse response from reactive call

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flatmap

Currently, I have a question, something like this:

```
WebClient.call(...)
       .flatMap(user -> webclient.call("host1",user.getId/*obj request*/);})//assume this return X.class
  (*)  .flatMap(x -> webclient.call("host2",user.getName/*obj request*/))//"x" is not used here, i want reuse object "user" but was compiled error, // assume this return Y.class
       .map(x -> webclient.call(...))// "x" is used here
```

### User

```
Class User {
    string id;
    string name;
}
```

### X

```
Class X {
    string deviceNo;
}
```

### Y

```
Class Y {
    Boolean isCorrect;
}
```

The question is how do I reuse correctly the "user" and the "x" response from the previous call?

### Here are my solutions for marked(*) place:

> 1. nested flatMap(), then can thenReturn(user) for next map().

Any issue with the scope of a variable(user) when I build a chain(nested flatMap...) like this so far?

```
       .flatMap(user -> { 
              return webclient.call("host1",user.getId/*obj request*/))
              .flatMap(x -> webclient.call("host2",user.getName/*obj request*/) //this consider as a side effect?
              .thenReturn(x));} still return "x"
       .map(x -> webclient.call(...))// "x" is used here
```

> 2. keep response by wrapping it in an object using map (i don't want to use this solution)

```
       .flatMap(user -> {
               return webclient.call("host1",user.getId/*obj request*/).map(x-> new X1(x, user)}))
       .flatMap(x1 -> webclient.call("host2", X1.GETUSER.GETNAME /*obj request*/).map(y -> new Y1(x1, y)}))
       .map(y1 -> webclient.call("host3",Y1.GETX1.X...))// "x" is used here
```

### X1, wrap x and user

```
Class X1 {
    public X1(x, user){}//contructor

    X x;
    User user
}
```

any idea, please help to review/advice
Thank you

Comment: what are you doing with the `Y` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is very opinionated.

i would personally use a [zipWith](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zipWith-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) operator which merges the results of 2 monos into a tuple.

```
WebClient.call(...)
    .flatMap(user -> webclient.call("host1",user.getId())
            .zipWith(webclient.call("host2",user.getName()))
    .flatMap(values -> {
        var x = values.getT1();
        var y = values.getT2(),
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I marked it as accepted IF this case we use "Y" response as T2 for next flatMap.
One more thing, Sir. If we don't need y(response from "host2") and consider it as a side effect, as my solution 1 then, how we use it correctly.